# how to insert data in datagridview's particular row from database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

In my datagridview (DGV) I have custom columns . In first column I have combo box . how can I display data in only that row on which the combo box value selected . for e.g. If I select value in combo box from 3rd row , corresponding data should display in 3rd row, not in 1st row and should not affect the other filled rows . if i select value from 6th row ,d data should be in 6th oe ..

I have no idea from  where to start .

Any suggestion .

thanks in advance ..

Comment: From where you getting amount of rows? How you know that datagridview need to have n rows?

Comment: i am adding rows on button click .......

Comment: Did you tried with [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

To insert database data from datagridview, you can set the Visible property of the Combo Box as False. The Combo box must not be visible when the form loads. The Combo Box will show up when the focus is on a Cell corresponding to the specific Column.

Comment: thanks ,that's what I am doing . but I can't fill the data in the corresponding  row when value is selected in combo box   .